# Logging on device to file

Tags: java, android, logging

How to redirect logging on device to file?

My application is hang on device but works great on emulator - I want to see logging on my device without sdk and its tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found excellent feature of Logcat. It can redirect output to file himself by using simple command parameter "-f ".
To use it you can write Logcat wrapper in your application aLogcat like. Obviously I made this :)

For using logcat at android I wrote this code:

```
Process proc = null;
try {
  proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", <!parametes_here!> });
  mReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()), 1024);
  String line;
  while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null) {
   if (line.length() == 0) {
    continue;
   }
  mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(Logcat.MSG_READ_LINE, line));
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start process", e);
} finally {
  if (mReader != null)
  try {
    mReader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot close stream", e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Android Log Collector](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/).

Answer (score 3):

[Microlog](http://microlog.microsuite.org/) - A logging framework for Java ME and Android inspired by Log4j.

(c) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j

["Using Microlog for Logging on Android & Viewing the Logs in the Emulator"](http://myossdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-microlog-for-file-logging-on.html) by Johan Karlsson

[Newsflash! Microlog for Android - microlog4android](http://myossdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/newsflash-microlog-for-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the application aLogCat downloaded free from android market.

Works very good.

Answer (score 0):

Logging frameworks like log4j already provide features like logging to a file. Using [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) it is possible to log to a rotating log file and to logcat. Also see [log4j support in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200138/1113228).