# How to get Android project and std Java project to play nice?

Tags: java, android, debugging

I can now get our Android project to talk to our non-Android project. But there's still an issue:

- I are trying to have an Android class call a non Android Hello World class.
- I tried compiling our non-Android Hello World class in a separate Eclipse workspace. I then packaged it into a jar. I imported that jar into our Android Hello World class.

I then called one of the methods in the non-Android Hello World class.

When I ran the Android Hello World class as an Android application, the following runtime error occurred. Here are the Android debug logs:

```
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at com.hello2.hello2.onCreate(hello2.java:27)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(I nstrumentation.java:1047)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(A ctivityThread.java:2627)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(Ac tivityThread.java:2679)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThr ead.java:125)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Activit yThread.java:2033)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99 )
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav a:4627)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit .java:626)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:118)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at helloArtifactJarTest.seconddirectory.TestJar.Hello PleasePleasePrint.<clinit>(HelloPleasePleasePrint. java:7)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): ... 14 more
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppende r(PropertyConfigurator.java:684)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategor y(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRoo tCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure( PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure( PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAnd Configure(OptionConverter.java:471)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.ja va:125)
08-11 09:07:56.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(333): ... 16 more
```

It seems that I can run HelloPleasePleasePrint as a Java application fine, with it properly using the log4j logger. But when we try calling a method in HelloPleasePleasePrint from the hello2 Android class, it complains about the log4j.

Any Help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You realize that Android doesn't use the Sun compiler, right? What happens when you compile the java source along with the Android code, rather than as a separate jar file?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the log4j errors, you can try to use [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). See [log4j support in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200138/1113228). It is important that the log4j system is not configured using a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file from the classpath.