# How to get log information in android

Tags: android, logging

How to get log information to remote server while app running on device. Like how we get in log of java file using log4j?

Comment: no i want my own log collector.i am doing client project

Comment: i need to get log of mobile to my server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for getting crash reports of app use following link

http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRA3HowTo?tm=6

Answer (score 4):

There is a service developed just for it (our company just released it): http://apphance.com. It is not only for reporting crashes, but also for reporting logs of your application running on remote devices. It is a service, so you do not need to have a server of your own - you just integrate a .jar file (less than 5 minutes - we timed it). And you immediately start getting the logs which you can look at in the web panel of ours. These are:

- logs from standard logging
- changes in conditions of the device (rotation, wifi/gprs etc.)
- crashes
- memory warning
- your testers can also report issues directly from the device including screenshots (yay!)

Disclaimer: I am CTO of Polidea, company behind apphance.

Answer (score 0):

Download Log Collecter from android market that app is useful to u

Answer (score 0):

@parag et al, Log Collector doesn't send the log (actually, open email chooser for you) in android 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new project, which enables log4j on android. Using lo4gj over slf4j is possible. It also provides an appender for LogCat. See project [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/) or [log4j support in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200138/1113228)