# Android: Can't get logs with SLF4J-Android

Tags: android, slf4j

I'm building a really simple Android project in ADT and using Maven. I have included both the slf4j-api and slf4j-android dependencies and I can see that everything is compiling properly. However, when I run or debug the application on my Nexus One, I don't see any log output. Is there a specific place I should be looking for these logs or should they be coming out in the Eclipse console?

For reference, here's my main activity:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeActivity.class);

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        logger.debug("onCreate");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say its not possible, as you are using slf4j-android. I dont think you can use normal slf4j with some other impl like log4j or logback. If you would have 2 slf4, its up to JVM which one would be loaded, so both wont work. If you want to log only to eclipse console use normal SLF4J + IMPL (log4j or logback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use slf4j as well for logging.  The log output shows up on the LogCat window.  I'm not sure if there's a way to see it in the Eclipse console.  In the Eclipse top-level menu, navigate to:  Window -> Show View -> Other.  When the dialog appears, expand "Android", and select "LogCat".  It doesn't show up by default, unfortunately.

HTH,

Kevin

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I thought it might be doing something like that. It's kind of weird that it formats it in the way it does, but hey, it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Android by default tells slf4j-android to not to log debug messages, and log4j is polite enough to honor that. Use the impolite https://github.com/mvysny/slf4j-handroid instead :)

Comment: Is it able to switch from Log to System.out if same module executed in JVM?

Comment: Sorry, that is currently not possible, and is probably against the slf4j philosophy that slf4j-impl should be a small library tailored to one logging backend only.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at using slf4j together with [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). Also see [log4j support in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200138/1113228).