# How to write data to file on starting

Tags: java, android

I am using below code to write data in a file.

```
public static void writeDataToFile(final String fileName, final String fileContents) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer.append(fileContents);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtility.logInfo(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here **FileWriter** Constructor takes boolean that means it concatenates data to file every time to the last data. What I am trying to get is to have a file that has logs of my activities I am performing. And I am achieving via above mentioned code. but the problem is it is always concatenating logs to the last of data every time. What I want is to write new log on starting ever time.By this I will not have search file to the bottom for last log. It will be on start evyer time. Any help

Comment: Why not saving a timestamp when the app is opened and use the timestamp to create the file, e.g. app_log_timestamp.log and write to it. This way you'd have a new log file every time the app is opened, so you can browse the latest logs easily. Might not be what you want, tho.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same. I am creating file with time stamp but every file is supposed to have huge logs...

Comment: why not using a logging lib? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915150/log4j-support-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If file does not exist, you have written code to create a new file.
Likewise, if file exists, you can delete the file, and create new one

Before deleting old file, you can copy contents into a String, and add them to content that is to be written in file before writing into file.

```
StringBuilder contentToWrite = new StringBuilder();
contentToWrite.append(newContent);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
} else {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    contentToWrite.append("\n\n" + sb);
    file.delete();
    file.createNewFile();
}
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
writer.append(contentToWrite);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

PS: Don't forget to close FileReader and BufferedReader in a finally statement.

Comment: If i delete file...previous data will be lost as well. I want to keep previous data as well. And further want to append new data at the head rather tail

Comment: I have updated the answer, if you might still need this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the append flag to false in the `FileWriter` constructor.  Then, use the `write()` function instead of the `append()` function

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
writer.write(fileContents);
```

Comment: This prepends the content - not what they want: `If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-

Comment: Yes, but it will also clear the file.  OP can do something to check whether or not he wants to clear the file, but this seems like a valid suggestion for a way to simply clear the file IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the file if it exists:

```
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    } else {
        file.delete()
        file.createNewFile();
    }
```

Comment: If i delete file...previous data will be lost as well. I want to keep previous data as well. And further want to append new data at the head rather tail