# how to compatible minSdk 21 to midSdk 26 version

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

basically i am using log4j library and one of their class supports minSdk 26 and currently i am using minSdk 21 but the problem is i cannot upgrade minSdk version to 26 .

So is there any way to compatible midSdk 21 to 26 .. Any help would be appreciated

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexQueueBusterAPPDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.tools.r8.a: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{"file":"/Users/jayantkumar/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/375628e22970e0d2f8484ffb87595408/jetified-log4j-api-2.19.0.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
```

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support but why are you using log4j? Is that needed for third-party libraries?

Comment: yes i need that library for storing logs data

Comment: From my link, did you try "To keep using that library with minSdkVersion 25 or lower, enable code shrinking to remove unused methods." If that doesn't work I would look to see if there Android compatible log4j library rather than the Java SE main library.

Comment: i tried that thing but still no result

Comment: You should explain why are you using log4j rather than something Android specific. Related: [log4j support in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2915150/295004)